# Adding dropdown menu to link in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

How can I add a dropdown menu to custom link in Boostrap?. It is described through official  [Bootstrap components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) page  how to add dropdown only for clickable buttons not for custom links.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/ffNQdPL40E)**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Link
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I have to include link within <div class="dropdown">?

Comment: You can include the link wherever you want. Please note that every `<li>` element into the dropdown has a `<a href>` link

Comment: I meant the "dropdown" class. It can be applied to span or div whatever the dropdown included into but not to ignore. Thanks for sharing :)